# Why is my padding doing this on bootstrap 3 navbar collapse?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question has three parts, I thought it would be best to ask all on here as there relevant to each other.

If this question is too much/over the top please advice and I will amend it.

**Issue #1**

Basically when my navbar collapses into a drop down menu the padding increases and leaves massive gapes between the links. as seen below;

[image]

**Resolved by removing line-height: 50px; from .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {**

**Issue #2**

I have a linebreak within the toggle mode, however I cant seem to get this to go below the logo. I'm guessing it has fix height of 50px, such as all the default settings on navbar.

[image]

**resoloved by  changing  due to my logo having a height of 100px** .

**Issue #3**

Is removing the scroll bar within the navbar

**resoloved by  changing max height in .navbar-collapse {max-height: 340px;} to 700px**

[image]

**NAVBAR CSS**

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: #191919;
    min-height: 100px !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    padding: 21px 25px 21px 25px;
    margin: 0!important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color: #1c1c1c;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    margin-right: 0px!important;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #2eb60f;
    display: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #191919;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #04fa00;
    color: #04fa00;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle  {
  border-color: #191919;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #191919;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse > li > a {
    padding: 2px 1px 2px 1px !important;
}
```

**HTML of navbar**

```
<div id="container">
     <header class="clearfix">
             <div class="navbar navbar-default">

             <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-vertical" style="font-size: 16px;color:#04fa00"></i>

                       </button>
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#">
                                <img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -16px;"
                                src="/images/mainlogo.png">
    </a>
</div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="testimonals.php">TESTIMONALS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.php">GALLERY</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="admin.php">ADMIN</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
             </div><!-- /.navbar navbar-default -->
     </header>

</div><!-- /.end container -->
```

Comment: I copied your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92r829yc/) and don't see anything even remotely close to the pictures. Can you recreate your problem on the fiddle?

Comment: @HristoValkanov http://jsfiddle.net/92r829yc/1/

Comment: That second scroll bar is caused by .navbar-collapse {max-height: 340px;} remove the max height all together or make it large (700px or so) and that will remove the scroll bar.

Comment: @GifCo thank you this has resolved the issue

Comment: To fix the line break add to <div class="navbar-header"> height:  100px;

Comment: @GifCo this has resolved this issue too, thanks :D

Comment: @GifCo if you answer with the 3 issues i will accept your answer.

Comment: No problem! :) the padding/line height seems to be multiple issues I would just play around in Chrome DevTools till you get it looking right. If you remove .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px !important;} YOu will see the drop down nav looks correct but it then messes up your normal expanded nav. Hopefully that helps a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st problem:**

To fix the line break that crosses through the logo.
.navbar-header { height: 100px; }

**2nd Problem.**

That second scroll bar is caused by

```
.navbar-collapse {max-height: 340px;}
```

remove the max height all together or make it larger to accommodate for the nav bar height.

**3rd problem.**

The padding/line height seems to be multiple issues. If you remove

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px !important;}
```

That will fix it for drop down but you will still have to adjust media query's for the expanded nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

Question1: It's your line-height that's making the links so spaced:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    ...
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Question2: I can't really tell without seeing the full page (is there a url we can check out or can you make a fiddle?)

Question3: It looks like you need an overflow: hidden; on one of the elements containing the nav, again it would be easier to debug in the full form.

Comment: removing the line-height has fixed the issue but forced my navbar to the right(i know i have navbar-right that does this) 

however with the line-height 50 it allowed the bar so sit level with the logo

Comment: I guess I would add your custom line-height to a media query `@media (min-width: 768px){ .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a { line-height: 50px; } } ` so that it doesn't interfere with the bootstrap styles on the smaller screen size

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can solve it by removing the line-height from your style. However, that would make your elements top aligned, they won't appear nice or vertically centred with the logo.

So, to do that, keep the line-height, and introduce a difference line-height based on the breaking point of your menu. Something like this using CSS would work:

**1st Issue:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
text-align:center;
line-height:1.7rem;
}}
```

**2nd Issue:**

As for the Second Issue with the border and the logo, that's easily solved by making your navbar-header accomodate your logo height:

```
.navbar-header {min-height:70px;} /* accomodate the logo height + some padding or whatever */
```

As for the third issue, I cannot seem to see it on the Fiddle I am afraid.

Here is a working fiddle for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/p8e9aLc9/11/

Comment: The third issue could not be reproduced on jsFiddle, and I can't even see it on your website. It looks fine in here. However, for issues 1 and 2, you can refer to the working fiddle in my answer!